# autoupdate Cell in Excel 2010 from JSON Webservice

Tags: json, web-services, excel, excel-2010

I'm looking for a solution to automatically update a cell in my Excel Table via a JSON Webservice. I've found a way to do this via XML, but unfortunately no way to do this via JSON.

The Webservice I want to use is: https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker

And I would like to use the value of return.avg.value in my table.

I even thought of using RegEx to get the value but I could't find a way to do so, also.

I really hope there is a solution to my problem without using a lot of different Addons and Plugins for Excel, so my table remains portable.

Thank you for your help,

Frederick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub TestJson()
    Dim json As String
    Dim sc As Object, o

    json = WebResponse("https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker")

    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    o = sc.Eval("eval(" & json & ")['return'].avg.value")

    Debug.Print o

End Sub



Public Function WebResponse(sURL As String) As String
    Dim XmlHttpRequest As Object
    Set XmlHttpRequest = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
    XmlHttpRequest.Open "GET", sURL, False
    XmlHttpRequest.send
    WebResponse = XmlHttpRequest.responseText
End Function
```

Comment: I'm getting Runtime Error 429 on `CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")` and `CreateObject("ScriptControl")`

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  If Yes then you'll need a different solution. I'm not familiar with that environment though.

Comment: There are a few different options for MSXML - a different one may work for you.  I'm on XP/Office 2010 and that one happened to work for me.  As for the script control - that may be a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue. I'm using 32-bit Office 2010.

Comment: `CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")` seems to work for me, is there an alternative for `CreateObject("ScriptControl")` too? This still breaks the macro.

Comment: I don't think there's a 64-bit version of the script control. It's possible you might be able to acheive the same result by automating IE. Or try a solution using something like this http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/ (I've never tried it).